# open a html file in web browser at a particular hyperlink using python

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

I am able to open an html file using the code

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new_tab('file:///C:/filename.html')
```

The issue I am facing is opening the same html file but with a hyperlink.

```
webbrowser.open_new_tab('file:///C:/filename.html#hyperlinkId')
```

This opens the file in the browser tab but does not move to the hyperlink as required.

Kindly let me know if I am missed anything.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @VipinJoshi:The mentioned link just has the option to open the html file in the browser which is working for me as well. The issue is with moving to the hyperlink.

Comment: @VipinJoshi The question already uses a URL, so I don't really get what you want to say with your comment. Also your example doesn't contain an anchor.